# Dynamic role based web app

Tags: jquery, jsp, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1, rbac

I am making a Java Enterprise Web App which uses EJB's as the business layer. I need to implement a dynamic RBAC. In the EJB side I can use security interceptor to check whther the method is invoked by a user having a particular role.

How should I handle this in UI? I do not want want to put my logic everywhere in my html/jsp files. I dont want to check if some button has this particular role or not. I want it to be dynamic and loaded from DB.

What I really desire is- Whenever a user logins, all his defined roles are kept in a session and all the webcomponents(buttons, links, etc) change accordingly. I dont code to be scattered in each jsp file for each element.

Can anyone give any ideas.

Thanks,
Anshu